# PalmWebOS tiny font

Tags: fonts, palm

I'm new to developing mobile websites and I have an issue with Palm Pre.
I wrote this simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
              Welcome!
    </body>
</html>
```

And then tested it with PalmPre - font is very tiny there. I tried e.g. with Opera Mini emulator and it looks just fine, Android don't seem to have any trouble.
What am I doing wrong here? I can of course set something like "font-size: 300%", but it will screw up display on other mobile devices.

I tried to google this without any luck, so any help is very much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting the meta viewport value, see [this page](http://learnthemobileweb.com/2009/07/mobile-meta-tags/) for information about metatags to mobile browsers render correctly.